# Strange issue in table rate shipping price

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, table-rates

I am using magento version 1.9.0.1. I have strange issue in shipping price which is set by table rate. Below is my `shipping_tablerate` table screenshot

[image]

I have set 7.36 for Andorra. but when i select on checkout page it display shipping price 6.08 EURO instead 7.36 EURO.

[image]

Comment: what is base currency for your store ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved issue.

Shipping price display including tax. I set price from tax menu in **system > configuration**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

By default magento store set price in dollar and whenever you aceess this price in your store magento convert price from base currency to default store currency

May be your base currency is in dollar and store currency in euro so magento convert 7.36 dollar to euro

Comment: base currency is euro

Comment: then check is there any discount applied to shipping price

Comment: There is no any discount on shipping